# Import a csv animation path using animation nodes

Tags: animation, scripting, import, animation-nodes, csv

In this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/importing-trajectories-to-create-an-animation), the answer shows how to use a script to import a CSV file and setup an animation. Is there a way to do this same thing using animation nodes?

[image: Empties following imported CSV path]

For example, this is start on the animation node network. However, it is not clear how to work with the 'Text File Reader' and convert the CSV data into list and then sequence through the list to change position and rotation. (Edit: this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46976/how-can-i-cast-a-text-element-to-float-in-animation-nodes?rq=1) shows a way to convert a text file into a list)

[image]

Comment: Kinda freaky ... jumped onto blender.se to ask almost the exact same question as an earlier very similar question (which you spotted) got me interested ... Hope you / we get an answer! Am also intrigued by a note in  your second link's accepted answer: "There are nodes that are not in the menu yet."  granted, that answer was Feb 2015, so maybe they're on the menu's now ... or is keeping some functionality hidden kind of standard practice (for pre-release testing say)?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file/61848#61848

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three solutions, with similar concept but a bit different on handling animation loop:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

NOTE: Here, I read the raw CSV file located at the same filepath to the blend file by using Text File Reader node. You can also copy and paste the CSV content to the internal Text Editor, then read it by Text Block Reader node.

Comment: The track creation part was very useful. Thanks!

Comment: thx Leon for all the effort here!  noob question: I can get your two examples working, but only with the Animation player (alt+A) ... how do we (cycles) render it via the Output panel? (Perhaps there's a 'render' node that we need to add in the node editor?)

Comment: Why you want to cycle render it (maybe I didn't get what you mean here)? And they are non-mesh objects, which cannot be rendered directly by hitting F12 or Ctrl F12, But you can do that with OpenGL render. Oh, BTW, I think you can also only create the tracks. For the walking-along-path animation, I think it is enough to use Blender's internal tools like Follow Path constraint, etc.

Comment: Just updated with 3rd solution, which is simply creating tracks, then let the mover follow it. This one is more efficient, less nodes used, and recommended.

Comment: thx for the reply and the 3rd solution, Leon.  I think I understand ... p1,p2,p3 are Empties, not objects ... I'd need "attach" objects where the empties are, to do cycles render. Yes? (Thanks for your patience, I'm still a bit of a noob :))

Comment: Aha, you mean Cycles Render engine, I see, just thought you were talking about sorta circular thing.  :P   Yes. empties and zero-width curves cannot be rendered by Cycles or BI. You can simply replace with other mesh objects as you want.