# Input 3D line segments from real scientific data

Tags: animation, scripting, import, animation-nodes, coordinates

I have collected 3D scientific information on a network of rod-like filaments with a particle moving though the filaments. The filaments are static and do not move. The output of the filament data from my analysis is two X,Y,Z points for each filament identified to create a line segment between the two points. For example if I have three separate filaments the information would be stored in a CSV file organized in a table as below:

ID | X1 | Y1 | Z1 | X2 | Y2 | Z2 |
1
2
3

The output of the particle moving data is similarly stored in a csv file organized with an X,Y,Z position and a Time as below:

Time | X1 | Y1 | Z1 |
1
2
3
4
...

What I would like is to create a static environment from the line segment data and then have an animation of the particle where each frame of the animation the particle is at its given X,Y,Z position for that time point.
The organization of these filaments (line segments) and the particle in 3D space and in relation to each other must remain accurate, to scale, and precise. This is scientific data and there is no room for any artistic license. Does anyone know how this information can be brought into blender so I can create animations of the particle moving though the network of filaments using this data? It's totally reasonable for me to reorganize my input files to better fit blenders mechanisms so the files do not need to remain as X,Y,Z coordinates if other solutions exist.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I was able to amend this previously answered question ( [Can object parameters be set from data file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file) ) to get at the particle moving in time part of this but am still having trouble with the line segments. If anyone can help with just that part I'd  appreciate it.

Comment: My answer to [visualising atom structures](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43631/935) places spheres and links them with tubes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you where trying to do well, the best way to create the segments is to use `curve object output`. With the `Spline from points` node, you can connect all you file data into the two vectors for the object, and animate them by using the method shown in the question [can object parameters be set from data file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file).

[image]

(In the image I let the vector inputs free)

Then you can create a loop or a group to repeat the process and create plenty of splines (segments)