# moving 3D object using csv file

Tags: csv

I am new to blender and I'm trying to move the cube using XYZ csv file. How can I merge the file with the object and make it moving using that file. Can someone help me. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is in the CSV files? Is this a set of points for animation?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87374/keyframed-animation-from-csv-using-animation-nodes might also be useful to you