# Animating plane with position, rotation and scale from data inside a text file

Tags: scripting

I want to animate a plane xyz coordinates, its scale on xyz and its rotation on the z axis based on a text file data where each line its a frame.

Example text file:

```
2265.48 563.242 0 166.402 166.402 100 7.3225
2266.61 562.668 0 166.529 166.529 100 7.32268
2267.35 562.864 0 166.622 166.622 100 7.32859
...
```

Where the data is organized like this:

```
[x coordinate] [y coordinate] [z coordinate] [x scale] [y scale] [z scale] [z rotation]
```

I dont have experience in python so i would like a helping hand if possible.

Comment: This would be relatively easy (at least for me, as i'm not very experienced in python either) using animation nodes (that's a free add on for node-based animation). If that's fine for you, I'll have a look when I'm home.

Comment: Yea, nodes are fine as long as i can take the data from the file and get it into blender. I didn't know there was a addon able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, i ended up using animation nodes to do that. Very easy to setup and work with the nodes. This thread also helped (it was basically what i wanted to do): [Answer from [Can object parameters be set from data file?]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)