# import positions and orientation into a camera

Tags: scripting, camera

hello I have a list of positions and orientations in the form of x y z, and rotX, rotY,rotZ

I have a script in my game that saves the position of my camera each frame and I need to play that back in a blender camera so I can do a render.

Also one thing, my game engine uses Y as height and I know blender doesn't.

Comment: What's your list format ? csv ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61605/import-a-csv-animation-path-using-animation-nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/python-script-that-reads-text-file-containing-coordinates-and-creates-a-path-cur/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points/76612 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-use-the-values-as-x-and-y-points-in-blender